# Testing Monadic Code

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm learning Haskell by working through the [Haskell course by Brent Yorgey](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/index.html). I just reached the monad section, and while I think I (finally) have a decent grasp on how to work with monads, I don't understand how to test code that uses them.

The exercise for this section is to write a (simplified) Risk simulation, and it requires heavy use of the `Rand StdGen` monad. In particular, we have to write the following function:

```
type Army = Int

data Battlefield = Battlefield { attackers :: Army, defenders :: Army }

battle :: Battlefield -> Rand StdGen Battlefield
```

It takes an initial battlefield, and runs a simulation of how this battle would go.

I have an implementation for it, but I don't understand how to test it. I can't "get at" the values inside the `Rand StdGen Battlefield` returned by `battle`, so I can't print them out at the GHCI interpreter, which is how I've been testing my code so far. I also can't figure out how to print the result of a battle in a Haskell main function, or something. How do people go about testing these sorts of functions?

Comment: You can "get at" the result of a random computation using functions like [`evalRand`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.1.3/docs/Control-Monad-Random.html) and friends. `evalRand` takes a 'starting' `RandomGen` and runs the monadic computation deterministically.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can "get at" the result of a random computation using functions like [`evalRand`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.1.3/docs/Control-Monad-Random.html) and friends. `evalRand` takes a 'starting' `RandomGen` and runs the monadic computation deterministically.

---

Here's my hand-waving, non-rigorous explanation of what `evalRand` is for:

One of the differences between monads and imperative programming is that a monad is a *representation* of a computation, not the computation itself. In other words, when Haskell evaluates an expression like `a >>= b >>= c` (or the equivalent `do` notation), it's just putting the Lego bricks together, so to speak - the computation doesn't take place until you *execute* the monad using a function like `evalRand`.

For a simpler example, think about composing functions together. `.` gives you a function which represents the computation carried out by the two functions it composes. You only get a return value from that computation when you actually call the function with an argument.

That's why many of the monads in the standard library (with the exception of `IO`, which is executed by the run-time system) provide a "trap door" function like `evalRand`. It's how you actually *use* the computation you just defined in your monadic code.

Comment: That's a useful way of thinking about a lot of monads, but it's *not* true of monads in general. The list monad doesn't defer computation until you call a "trap door" function (except due to laziness). It's only the monads which provide implicit access to some sort of environment that necessarily work the way you describe, and that's because e.g. a `Rand StdGen Int` represents a "probabilistic integer", which needs a `StdGen` to be provided to select a concrete `Int` from all the values it could be.

Comment: You're absolutely right, of course. Thanks for the comment. It provides some important context and balance to my qualitative description.